# Knockout.JS Doesn't Find Value Attribute In Select Tag When Data Comes From The Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

When I bind drop down list after `ajax` request `select` tag doesn't read `value` attribute. But when I bind the drop down list in the `view model` it `recognise` it for example:

**it is working if I bind the model like this**

```
var CostModel = function (data) {

var getCosts = getAllCosts.bind(this);
    getCosts();

var months = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'january' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'february' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'march' }, ];
this.months = ko.observableArray(months); //after this value is set by default with 'march'
```

}

but if I bind the model after the ajax request the source of all names from months array is binded but the selected item by default doesn't work in this example `value of 3`

```
function getAllCosts() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/CostManageView/List",
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            var months = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'january' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'february' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'march' }, ];

            self.months(ko.utils.arrayMap(months, function (month) {
                return new Month(month);
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

**html**

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.months,
                       optionsText: 'Name',
                       optionsValue: 'ID',
                       value: 3"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the ajax call will take some time to execute (asynchronously). However, the bindings are probably applied before the call is done. This results in the following:

1. Options binding is resolved
2. The value '3' is not an option in the select control, since $root.months is not yet filled (the call has yet to return)
3. Because of (2), the value of the select control will be reset to null/undefined (not entirely sure which one)
4. Your call returns and fills the observableArray $root.months. however, by now the value is null/undefined so march will not be selected.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/CostManageView/List",
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        var months = [{ ID: 1, Name: 'january' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'february' }, { ID: 3, Name: 'march' }, ];

        self.months(ko.utils.arrayMap(months, function (month) {
            return new Month(month);
        }));
        self.selectedMonth(3);
    }
});

<select data-bind="options: $root.months,
                   optionsText: 'Name',
                   optionsValue: 'ID',
                   value: $root.selectedMonth"></select>
```

If that works, then try to set `selectedMonth` AFTER the months are loaded.

Comment: So if the $root.months is not filled value automatically sets its value to null ? How can I be sure that this is the behaviour of the select binding ?

Comment: The easiest way to test this is with an observable like `selectedMonth` in my example. Try `selectedMonth.subscribe(console.log)`. This will write the value of selectedMonth to the console each time it changes. You can easily see what happens that way.